# Black screen when installing Ubuntu on Surface 3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, surface

I am new to to the ubuntu world and am eager to try it since I would like to break free from windows :)

I tried installing ubuntu and xubuntu on my surface 3 (4gb ram, 128 HDD, intel atom processor, full specs [here](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/surface-3-specs)) via usb to dual boot it alongside windows 10  but I get the same result: after briefly displaying the ubuntu/xubuntu logo, the screen goes black and stays that way.

I also tried booting live but I get the same result.

I was able to live boot linux mint but since it didn't support surface 3's touchscreen and touchpad it was useless to me.

Thank you all in avance!